# How to plot the distribution of several assets within the same portfolio in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, finance, portfolio

I have this portfolio composed of three assets below

```
# import some libraries
from pandas_datareader import data as wb
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
import math
# get the stock symbols in our portfolio
assets = ['AAP','NFLX','BA']

# assign weights to our portfolio 
weights = np.array([0.2, 0.3, 0.5])
# get the portfolio start date
stockStartDate = '2020-01-01'

# get the portfolio ending date 
today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# create a dataframe to store the adjusted close price of the price
df = pd.DataFrame()

# store the adjusted close price pf the stock into the df
for stock in assets : 
  df[stock] = wb.DataReader(stock, data_source = 'yahoo', start = stockStartDate, end = today)['Adj Close']

# visually show the portfolio

title = 'Portfolio Adjusted Close Price History'

#get the stocks
my_stocks = df

# create & plot the graph
for c in my_stocks.columns.values:
  plt.plot(my_stocks[c], label = c)

plt.title(title)
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize = 18)
plt.ylabel('Adj. Price USD($)')
plt.legend(my_stocks.columns.values, loc = 'upper left')
plt.show()
```

Which lead to this result:
[Portfolio Adjusted Price History](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8lfTp.png)

I've been able to have one graph for the portfolio as a whole with the code below

```
returns = df.pct_change()
df1 = returns

mean = sum(weights)/len(weights)
var = sum(pow(x-mean,2) for x in weights) / len(weights)
std = math.sqrt(var)
x_min = df1.min()*100
x_max = df1.max()*100

mean = mean
std = std
#x_axis = np.arange(x_min, x_max,0.01)
x_axis = np.arange(-20,20,0.01)
plt.plot(x_axis, norm.pdf(x_axis, mean, std))
plt.xlabel('returns')
plt.ylabel('Frequency density')
plt.title('Returns Distributions for N = 1')
plt.show()
```

And the following code:

```
for d in returns.columns:
  plt.plot(returns[d], label = d)

plt.title(title)
plt.xlabel('Date', fontsize = 18)
plt.ylabel('Adj. Price USD($)')
plt.legend(my_stocks.columns.values, loc = 'upper left')
plt.show()
```

However the result I want to have are the ones below:
[Asset price distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxA8k.png) and
[Asset gross return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRVU0.png)

Can you please help on being able to compute both graphs?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Not quite sure what you are trying to do, are you trying to have a plot with two different y-axes? Or two subplots side-by-side? Also, more people will be more willing to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) with some dummy sample data.

Comment: Hi Xicocaio, thanks for the feedback, indeed what I want to have is the 3 assets subplots side-by-side

Comment: Have you tried creating subplots `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)`? If you are not restricted to use pure `matplot` you should definitely try the `seaborn` package for automatically handling multiple plots.

Comment: I tried this code below
```
# making subplots objects
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

for e in returns.columns:
  plt.plot(returns[e], label = e)
plt.show()
```
However I got two differents graph and only one of them is "plotted"

Comment: I believe you are calling `plt.plot()`, when you should be calling `ax.plot()`.